# unable to find App_start folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was unable to find  App_Start folder in my MVC4 application. I was already tried  "show all files" option in solution explorer. Even though I didn't got the folder. so, anyone give me a solution to find the folder.

Answer (score 3):

This folder is automatically added by the Wizard when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application in Visual Studio. If you cannot find it that's probably because somebody deleted it. You could always add it manually if necessary.

Comment: You can also add code to any folder. You don't need this folder.